# java.util.NoSuchElementException on getConnection()

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have the following code:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext(); // Set the initial context
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/" + serverURL);        
conn = dataSource.getConnection();
```

However, the line `conn = dataSource.getConnection();` is throwing a `java.util.NoSuchElementException`. I'm a bit confused by this. Does this mean my server URL is incorrect? Here is my context.xml:

```
<Context>
    <Resource name=serverURL auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" url="jdbc:db2://"
        username="" password="" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" />

</Context>
```

and here is my web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>

        <res-ref-name>serverURL</res-ref-name>

        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>

        <res-auth>Application</res-auth>

        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>

    </resource-ref>
```

Anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try so -

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup(serverURL);
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
// ...
```

See also [JNDI Datasource HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)

Comment: Same result with this.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.NoSuchElementException` is thrown by the connection pool when it has run out of connections. Chances are you have a connection leak. You could try enabling abandoned connection logging to find out where the leak is.

Update:

If you see this with the first connection then it could well be the URL. Some Googling indicates that the format for the connection URL is `jdbc:db2://<host>[:<port>]/<database_name>`. Your URL is missing the host name and database name. If the port is not standard then you'll need to specify the port too.

Comment: If this is the cause, then looks like OP's not closing the connections after using them.

Comment: That is the first connection that I open in my program.

Comment: @JohnRoberts then the problem seems to be that you have a problem in your datasource configuration or you're not sending the right resource JDNI name.

Comment: Wouldn't serverURL be the host? Mine is of the form "jdbc/xxxxxxxx".

Comment: A `DataSource` should not throw a `NoSuchElementException` if the pool is exhausted, it should either block until a connection comes available or throw a `SQLException`. In other words, this is a bug in the pool implementation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel What do you mean a bug in the pool implementation? So there is a bug in context.xml?

Comment: @JohnRoberts No, a connection pool should not throw that exception, so if it is your connection pool that throws a `NoSuchElementException`, then it is a bug in the connection pool

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I do not have a connection pool manually coded out. All the code I have regarding the question is provided.